# concat two array on every second place

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have Array like my var bar and I would like  to add var test on every second place in array.

```
var test = "foo";

var bar = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"];

var new = ["Wilson 1", "foo" "Wilson 2", "foo"];
```

I tried with concat but no results:

```
var new = bar.concat(test);
```

Comment: i think your problem exists in define a variable. in `var new` , `new` is Reserved Word in javascript. please see this link [JavaScript Reserved Words](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) and [how define variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function for this, so you have to do this yourself. How would you solve it? I would

- Create a new array
- Loop through the old array(bar)
- For every iteration of bar, I would add an item to the new array + the string you want.

**edit**

All the other answers are so bad, I feel compelled to add a full example:

```
const test = "foo";
const bar = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"];

const newA = [];

for (const item of bar) {
  newA.push(item, test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved ith a simple for-loop

```
var test = "foo";
var bar = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"];
var newA = [];

for (var i = 0; i < bar.length; i ++) {
    newA.push(bar[i]);
    newA.push(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6's  `spread` operator, `array.prototype.concat` and `array.prototype.map`:

```js
var test = "foo";

var bar = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"];

var result = [].concat(...bar.map(e => [e, test]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @JordiCastilla I've fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `while` loop and splice the value as each second item.

```js
var item = "foo",
    array = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"],
    i = 1;

while (i <= array.length) {
    array.splice(i, 0, item);
    i += 2;
}

console.log(array);
```

Or use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var item = "foo",
    array = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a, item), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
var new = bar.map((m, i) => (m).concat(new Array(test[i])));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.forEach()`:

```
var test = "foo";

var bar = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"];

var newArr = [];

bar.forEach(el => newArr.push(el, test))

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array#reduce`

```js
var test = "foo",
    bar = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"],
    result = bar.reduce((r,v) => {
      r.push(v, test);
      return r;
    },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a perfect example where reduce is in every way inferior to a regular loop.

Comment: Why do you think the regular loop is better than `array#reduce` ?

Comment: It's unnecessary, slower, harder to read and doesn't actually provide any benefits. Array functions shouldn't be your default, primitives should be. Use these functions when they make things simpler. This is not one of those cases.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.reduce` and in it append the `current element` and `test`

```js
var test = "foo";
var bar = ["Wilson 1", "Wilson 2"];

var newArr = bar.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat([el, test]) , []);

console.log(newArr);
```